# To prove $r \cdot f_1 +f_2 \cdot (s+1)$ is secure

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, provable-security, protocol-analysis

We define the polynomials $r, f_1,f_2,s \in R[x]$. Where $r$ is a random degree 1 polynomial and $s$ is a random polynomial such that: $degree(s)=degree(f_1)=degree(f_2)$, let $R$ be $\mathbb{Z}_p$ where $p$ is a large prime number.

My question: " How to To prove: Given $\ r\cdot f_1 +f_2 \cdot (s+1)$ one who knows only $f_2$ cannot learn anything about $f_1$."

---

Or even simpler: Given $\ f_1 +f_2 \cdot s$, one who knows $f_2$ can learn anything about $f_1$?

Thanks

Comment: I have proof when the degree of $r$ is the same as degree of $f_1$ : https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~leak/papers/set-tech-full.pdf  but here I need $r$ to be of degree one.

Comment: Let ignore +1 in s+1 and make the situation a bit worse. So we would have $ r \cdot f_1 \cdot f_2 + f_2 \cdot s= f_2(r \cdot f_1+s)$, since $(r \cdot f_1+s)$ is distributed uniformly at random in $R^d[x]$, one knows $f_2$ cannot learn anything about $f_1$

Comment: One more question. Multiplying two polynomials increases the degree of the polynomial. Basically the degrees add. You aren't doing any dimensionality reduction step (like we typically see with shamir based MPC), are you?

Comment: @mikeazo No, I don't need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a fact.

For some polynomial $f_x$ and some random polynomial of the same degree, say $t$, an adversary given only $f_x+t$, knows no additional information about $f_x$. Basically (due to the finite ring), this operation is the same thing as the one-time-pad.

On to the problem at hand.

Let $f_3=f_2\cdot(s+1)$. Since $f_2$ and $s$ have the same degree, we know that $f_3$ has double that degree. Say the degree of $s$ (and $f_2$ and $f_1$) is $d$, so the degree of $f_3$ is $2d$. Since $2d>d$ (when $d>0$), if you could prove that $f_3$ was a random polynomial, then clearly an attacker given the values you specified above would learn no additional information about $f_1$. Problem is, $f_3$ is not a random polynomial since the coefficients would have interdependencies. For example (using $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$), let $f_2=3x+5$ and $s=7x+2$, then $f_3=(7*3)x^7+(2*3+5*7)x+(5*2)=10x^2+8x+10$. The terms (before I reduced the multiplication) have interdependencies.

Since $f_3$ is not random, Adding $f_3$ to another non-random polynomial ($f_1$ or $r\cdot f_1$ in your case) would not be indistinguishable from a random polynomial. So, I don't think you can make an information theoretic argument.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It's been shown in https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~leak/papers/set-tech-full.pdf that if  $ degree (r)=degree(f_1)=degree(f_2)=degree(s)$, where $gcd(f_1,f_2)=1$ then $\ U= r \cdot f_1 + f_2 \cdot s$ has coefficients uniformly distributed in $R$. I just changed the degree of $r$ to 1.

Comment: Looking over that paper, they say that given $f*r + g*s$, where $f$ and $g$ are the polynomial representations of $S$ and $T$ respectively and $r$ and $s$ are random polynomials of degree $deg(f)$, the attacker learns no additional information about $S$ and $T$ than what can be deduced from $S\cap T$. Not sure how this directly translates to your problem.

Comment: Their Lemma 2 does specifically have that $degree(r)$ and $degree(s)$ $>$ $degree(f_1)$ (and $f_2$). Not sure if it can be extended to the case where $degree(r)=1$. Just checking, you do mean degree $1$ for $r$ and not $0$ (a random constant), right?

Comment: In our case $degree(r)=1$.

Comment: Since in that paper $ r,s \leftarrow R^d[x]$, where $R^d[x]$ is the set of polynomials of degree 0,...,d, I think it's clear we can have $degree(r) < degree(f)$ .

Comment: Looking at Lemma 2, $r,s$ have degree $\beta$ where $\beta\geq\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the degree of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Yes, but a paragraph up, the defined $r,s \leftarrow R^d[x]$, confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18834/discussion-between-mikeazo-and-user153465).

Comment: Trying to add/invite you. Are you the other person in the room?